# XML Serialization of an object initialized as array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, xml-serialization

My question is probably arising from a basic misunderstanding of XML serialization, but anyways...
I'm trying to serialize a class containing an object which was initialized with an array using XMLSerializer class. Minimal example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XMLSerializationTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        try
        {                
            string xmlFileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\somename.xml";
            XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
            FileStream file = File.Create(xmlFileName);
            MyClass someclass = new MyClass();
            writer.Serialize(file, someclass);
            file.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }        
}
public class MyClass
{
    public object myObject;
    public MyClass()
    {
        myObject = new string[1] { "somestring" };
    }
}
}
```

However, this throws System.InvalidOperationException, reading the array can't be used here. It works fine, if one replaces the array within the MyClass constructor, e.g., with a simple string like `myObject = "somestring";`. Unfortunately, I just don't know if my object will be an array or not in advance. So is there any possibility to solve this problem e.g. with attributes or is XML just the wrong way to go in this case?

Comment: Do you know all possible types of objects that could be saved in `myObject` in advance?

Comment: Adding an array definition to serialization adds an unnecessary tag to the xml.  For example the tag items isn't required : <root><items><item>a</item><item>b</item><item>c</item></items></root>.  Here is same without the tag items : <root><item>a</item><item>b</item><item>c</item></root>.  Both xml are vaild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your difficulty arises from the fact that `XmlSerializer` requires all types to be serialized to be discoverable statically, through reflection.  However, your type `MyClass` has a polymorphic `object` property where a instance of a subtype of `object` -- specifically `string []` -- is being stored.  When `XmlSerializer` encounters it, since objects of this type are not expected, the serializer throws the exception you see.

When serializing polymorphic properties such as this, it is necessary to use [XML serialization attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx) to declare the types that can be encountered.  `XmlSerializer` provides two mechanisms to accomplish this.

1. Declare the possible polymorphic subtypes using [`XmlInclude(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attributes on the containing type.  Since `string` and `string []` are the possible types of your `object` property, you would do:

   ```
   [XmlInclude(typeof(string))]
   [XmlInclude(typeof(string[]))]
   public class MyClass
   {
       public object myObject { get; set; }

       public MyClass()
       {
           myObject = new string[] { "somestring" };
       }
   }
   ```

   And the resulting XML will look like:

   ```
   <MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <myObject xsi:type="ArrayOfString">
           <string>somestring</string>
       </myObject>
   </MyClass>
   ```

   Notice the [`xsi:type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx) attribute?  That is a [w3c standard attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) that allows the element to assert its type explicitly.  Its presence allows `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the XML into the same type of objects as were originally serialized.

   (Note that `[XmlInclude(typeof(string))]` seems to be unnecessary as `string` is apparently a built-in known type - though I cannot find documentation confirming this.)
2. Declare the possible polymorphic subtypes using [`[XmlElement(String, Type)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz6bdh5z.aspx) on the polymorphic property itself.  Thus you would do something like:

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       [XmlElement("myObjectString", typeof(string))]
       [XmlElement("myObjectStringArray", typeof(string[]))]
       public object myObject { get; set; }

       public MyClass()
       {
           myObject = new string[] { "somestring" };
       }
   }
   ```

   And the XML generated will look like:

   ```
   <MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <myObjectStringArray>
           <string>somestring</string>
       </myObjectStringArray>
   </MyClass>
   ```

   Notice that the name of the `myObject` element been modified to the string passed to into the `[XmlElement(String, Type)]` attribute constructor.  This allows `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the XML into the same type of objects as were originally serialized.